# Run a logon script etc once for any user

Tags: windows, login-script

I'm not sure this is actually possible or not, but maybe someone here has run into the same issue and found a good way.

Q: How to create a logon script that only runs once for a user on a computer/terminal server?

A bit of background:
I am aware that in theory it is possible to create a logon script that checks if a file exists on a location the user can access and if that file exists, abort the script, then at the end of the logon script, create that file. In essence this would do what I want, but it would still run the script at every logon, and I'm curious if there's a better way.

The problem I want to solve:
When a user runs MS Teams for the first time it will set auto start to true and the user always gets MS Teams started. For a terminal server where users only use teams occasionally, it is preferred to not auto-start teams and let the user start teams themselves.

I have a script that I have to run once per user that will alter the json config for teams and set the flag to false. Users have profile disks so I cannot do a global sweep to alter it for everyone once.
The script, once run will fix it forever for that user, so I really only need to run it once.

There is the runonce registry setting to start a program once. Is there a loginscript equivalent that I can push through GPO such that a login script is run only once for any given user, but is not removed so all users get to run it once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting
[RunOnce](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys)
in the registry for all users may do the job,
but is a bit messy to implement
([example](https://www.pdq.com/blog/modifying-the-registry-of-another-user/)).

Windows has a simple mechanism for running a command very early in the
logon process, called Active Setup.
Windows uses this same mechanism for its message to new users of
"Setting up personalized settings", but it will also work for existing users.

This works by Windows comparing the Active Setup registry key of the machine profile
(HKLM) against the current user profile (HKCU) copy of the subkey.
In case of mismatch, it runs the indicated command and then sets HKCU to match
HKLM, signifying that there is no need to run it again.

You may examine whether the Active Setup method suits your needs and your environment.

All you need are two registry values for Active Setup updated once on the computer,
to run a command for all logins only once.
This example will run `notepad`:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\LPChip]
@="LPChip's Active Setup Component"
"StubPath"="notepad"
```

References:

- [Active Setup Explained](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2010/04/active-setup-explained/)
- [An Active Setup Primer](https://www.itninja.com/blog/view/an-active-setup-primer)

---

As Active Setup is executed by `explorer.exe`, this creates a problem
with Terminal Server, where Explorer is not the shell.

Microsoft has created an alternative solution : `RailRunonce`.
This is found in the registry at
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\RailRunonce`.

The problem with `RailRunonce` is that it does not do versioning,
so the solution is to couple it with Active Setup,
by creating under the above key a value with an arbitrary name
that contains this command:

```
%systemroot%\system32\runonce.exe /AlternateShellStartup
```

The process `runonce.exe` is the one that Windows uses for processing
the `RunOnce` registry key.
The main point to remember is that the execution here will be in parallel
and will not pause the user process.

Reference:
[Article: A Deep Dive into Active Setup: Part 4 – The Finale](http://ftsctest.com/blog/article-a-deep-dive-into-active-setup-part-4-the-finale/),

Comment: This is very interesting indeed. Question though, if I have an environment where users login to a TS farm with multiple servers, will it still understand it that it runs just once for that user, not once per server? So far Active Setup seems to run once per server.

Comment: I have add a part for TS which might work better in your case.

Comment: Thanks. I have to do a bit of research to see how well this works for what I need, but looks promising. :)